# Combining two integer columns without addition

Tags: python, pandas, integer

I have two columns:

```
Data = {'Col1': [1 , 2 , 3 , 0 , 0 , 4] , 'Col2': [0 , 2 , 0 , 5 , 6 , 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = Data)
df.head()

Col1    Col2
0   1    0
1   2    2
2   3    0
3   0    5
4   0    6
5   4    4
```

I want to create a third column which combines these two, but does not add the cells.
I want a dataset like the following:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
0   1    0    1
1   2    2    2
2   3    0    3
3   0    5    5
4   0    6    6
5   4    4    4
```

I've simply added the two columns, but this solution adds the values existing in both columns.
The solution is probably very easy, but i couldn't wrap my head around it...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check `df['Col3'] = df.max(1)`

Comment: Can you select the max method on certain columns? For instance df['Col3'] = df[['Col1 , Col2]].max(1)

Comment: yes, you can select multiple columns..

Comment: df['Col3'] = df.max(axis=1). axis=1 for denoting that you're finding the max for the rows.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I works wonders!